# How to prevent stack overflow when dealing with long recursive productions in C?

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-construction, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Given a grammar, how can one avoid stack overflow problem when calculating FIRST and FOLLOW sets in C. The problem arose in my code when I had to recurse through a long production.

Example:

```
S->ABCD
A->aBc | epsilon
B->Bc
C->a | epsilon
D->B
```

That is just a grammar off-head. The recursion is as such:

```
S->A
C->A
A->B
B->D
D->aBc | epsilon
```

> ```
> FIRST(S)=FIRST(A)=FIRST(B)=FIRST(D)={a,epsilon}.
> ```
>
> Provide a C (not C++) code that calculates and print FIRST and FOLLOW set of the grammar above keeping in mind that you might encounter a longer grammar that has multiple implicit first/follow sets of a particular non-terminal.

For example:

```
FIRST(A)=FIRST(B)=FIRST(B)=FIRST(C)=FIRST(D)=FIRST(E)=FIRST(F)=FIRST(G)=FIRST(H)=FIRST(I)=FIRST(J)=FIRST(K)={k,l,epsilon}.
```

> That is: for you to get `FIRST(A)` you have to calculate `FIRST(B)` and so on until you get to `FIRST(K)` that has its `FIRST(K)` has terminals `'k'`,`'l'`, and `epsilon`. The longer the implication, the more likely you will encounter stack-overflow due to multiple recursion.
>   How can this be avoided in C language and yet still get the correct output?
>   Explain with a C (not C++) code.

```
char*first(int i)
{
    int j,k=0,x;
    char temp[500], *str;
    for(j=0;grammar[i][j]!=NULL;j++)
    {
        if(islower(grammar[i][j][0]) || grammar[i][j][0]=='#' || grammar[i][j][0]==' ')
        {
           temp[k]=grammar[i][j][0];
           temp[k+1]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
            if(grammar[i][j][0]==terminals[i])
            {
                temp[k]=' ';
                temp[k+1]='\0';
            }
            else
            {
                x=hashValue(grammar[i][j][0]);
                str=first(x);
                strncat(temp,str,strlen(str));
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My code goes to stack overflow. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is overflowing the stack not because the grammar is "too complex" but rather because it is left-recursive. Since your program does not check to see if it has already recursed through a non-terminal, once it tries to compute `first('B')`, it will enter an infinite recursion, which will eventually fill the call stack. (In the example grammar, not only is `B` left-recursive, it is also *useless* because it has no non-recursive production, which means that it can never derive a sentence consisting only of terminals.)

That's not the only problem, though. The program suffers from at least two other flaws:

- It does not check if a given terminal has already been added to the **FIRST** set for a non-terminal before adding the terminal to the set. Consequently, there will be repeated terminals in the **FIRST** sets.
- The program only checks the first symbol in the right-hand side. However, if a non-terminal can produce ε (in other words, the non-terminal is *nullable*), the *following* symbol needs to be used as well to compute the **FIRST** set.

  For example,

  ```
  A → B C d
  B → b | ε
  C → c | ε
  ```

  Here, **FIRST**(*A*) is `{b, c, d}`. (And similarly, **FOLLOW**(*B*) is `{c, d}`.)

Recursion doesn't help much with the computation of **FIRST** and **FOLLOW** sets. The simplest algorithm to describe is the this one, similar to the algorithm presented in the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), which will suffice for any practical grammar:

1. For each non-terminal, compute whether it is nullable.
2. Using the above, initialize **FIRST**(*N*) for each non-terminal *N* to the set of *leading symbols* for each production for *N*. A symbol is a leading symbol for a production if it is either the first symbol in the right-hand side or if every symbol to its left is nullable. (These sets will contain both terminals and non-terminals; don't worry about that for now.)
3. Do the following until no **FIRST** set is changed during the loop:

   - For each non-terminal *N*, for each non-terminal *M* in **FIRST**(*N*), add every element in **FIRST**(*M*) to **FIRST**(*N*) (unless, of course, it is already present).
4. Remove all the non-terminals from all the **FIRST** sets.

The above assumes that you have an algorithm for computing nullability. You'll find that algorithm in the Dragon Book as well; it is somewhat similar. Also, you should eliminate useless productions; the algorithm to detect them is very similar to the nullability algorithm.

There is an algorithm which is usually faster, and actually not much more complicated. Once you've completed step 1 of the above algorithm, you have computed the relation **leads-with**(*N*, *V*), which is true if and only if some production for the nonterminal *N* starts with the terminal or non-terminal *V*, possibly skipping over nullable non-terminals. FIRST(*N*) is then the transitive closure of **leads-with** with its domain restricted to terminals. That can be efficiently computed (without recursion) using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, or using a variant of Tarjan's algorithm for computing strongly connected components of a graph. (See, for example, [Esko Nuutila's transitive closure page.](http://www.cs.hut.fi/~enu/tc.html))

Comment: This explains the algorithm clearly . I would love to see a sample code in C.The code will settle everything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer was written in this way to help you to learn and solve the problem since this seems to be a class assignment. Writing a solution wouldn't serve that goal.